# Why the worst case for Dijkstra is E + VlogV?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Shouldn't it be E*(logV)? Reference: [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Please explain why you think this algorithm should be E(logV).

Comment: Yeah sorry, Dijkstra made a typo.

Comment: Common implementations *are* O(|E| log |V|).  You need a priority queue that supports constant-time decrease-key operations to get the better asymptotic bound.  Your link points this out.

Answer (score 4):

The worst case time complexity of [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) depends on how it's implemented:

[Simple Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode): `O((E * c1) + (V * V)) = O(E + V^2) ~ O(V^2)`

[Using Fibonacci Heap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42561/Dijkstra-s-Algorithm-for-Network-Optimization-Usin): `O((E * c2) + (V * log V)) = O(E + V log V) ~ O(V log V)`

Comment: For your analysis of the heap solution - This is inaccurate if it's a dense graph where E = V^2. In that case, the worst case would still be O(E) = O(V^2).

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case `E > V` so the complexity is `E + VlogV` which can be replaces with `E+ElogV` that as for complexity is `ElogV` is that what you mean ?